# Does enumerate over slice perform sublist materialization?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does this:

```
for i,v in enumerate(lst[from:to]):
```

or this:

```
for  i,v in enumerate(itertools.islice(lst,from,to)):
```

...make a copy of iterated sublist?

Comment: First yes, second no.

Comment: Why not perform an experiment? Mutate the slices that you iterate over. Does this change the original object?

Comment: @JohnColeman How would you do that for the second version?

Comment: If you're going to have to pause and resume... why not store it outside the loop, `it = enumerate(lst)`, then `for i, v in it: #... whatever and break`, then you can re-use `it` after again and it'll resume from where you broke. (If that's what you're trying to do by list slicing - but I'm not sure...)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Good question. I just noticed that `'itertools.islice' object does not support item assignment` so it isn't as easy as I thought it would be to see that it isn't a copy. In the first case a simple experiment (on the slice itself -- `enumerate` is a bit of a distraction) will show that the slice is a copy rather than an alias.

Comment: @JohnColeman In both cases, you can just modify the _original_ list and see whether the slice or the islice will be affected.

Comment: @JohnColeman Actually, what if Python used a lazy "copy on change" mechanism, so that creating a slice doesn't copy, but modifying causes the slice to be copied? Then your experiment would falsely suggest that creating a slice makes a copy.

Comment: @tobias_k That is a clever idea. You would first need to store the slice or islice in a variable, after which is is easy to verify that the islice stays linked to the original list but the slice doesn't. Perhaps you could write this up as an answer.

Comment: @StefanPochmann In Python you can perform experiments to differentiate between copies and aliases. You are certainly correct that such experiments can't settle questions about what Python does under the hood. I'm not 100% sure, but I think that R follows that "copy on change" strategy. Do you know if there are any contexts in which Python does?

Comment: @JohnColeman I can only think of `+=` for strings, which might modify the ostensibly immutable string if there's only one reference to it, but copies+modifies otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `lst` is a regular Python list, and not a Numpy array, Pandas dataframe, or some custom class supporting slice indexing, then the slice `[...:...]` will create a new list, whereas [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) does not.

As suggested in comments, you can see this for yourself by creating both `enumerate` objects and modifying the original list before consuming them:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> e1 = enumerate(lst[1:4])
>>> e2 = enumerate(itertools.islice(lst, 1, 4))
>>> del lst[2]  # remove second element
>>> list(e1)
[(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4)]  # shows content of original list
>>> list(e2)
[(0, 2), (1, 4), (2, 5)]  # second element skipped
```

Also note that this does in fact have nothing to do with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), which will create a generator in both cases (on top of whatever iterable was created before by the slice).

You could also just create the two variants of slices and check their types:

```
>>> type(lst[1:4])
list  # a new list
>>> type(itertools.islice(lst, 1, 4))
itertools.islice  # some sort of generator
```